# please help me with rad controls in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, editor, rad-controls

I want to use rad editor in sharepoint

I have tried to install tellerik controls in sharepoint and i am getting  this error

"Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI\,' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified".

could anyone help me in trying to figure out this error.

Please let me know if any one know how to use rad editor in sharepoint

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the assembly for your page.
Take a look at this [post](http://blog.richfinn.net/2008/05/07/IntegratingNewestTelerikRadControlsForASPNETAJAXIntoSharePoint.aspx), it shows how to do what you need.

You should add this to your page:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
```

Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the the dlls files in the bin folder